# How to get the actual image when a thumbnail is found?

Tags: java, html, image, image-processing, thumbnails

I am crawling images with Nutch. My code works in a way when it just finds an  tag, it processes the found image. It works perfectly fine but there is one problem, in the process a significant number of thumbnails are crawled and processed, while I need the actual images. In some cases I do get the actual image as well along with its thumbnail but in many cases I don't find the actual image in the set of images I have crawled. This snapshot from a wallpapers collection website may help to understand the situation, where these thumbnails are crawled and processed instead of the actual images.

[image]

Following is a simple sketch of the code.

```
while(nodeWalker.hasNext()){
             //some code

  if("img".equalsIgnoreCase(nodeName) && nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

            //image detected 
            //get image Url, do more.....
  }
}
```

I searched on the web but couldn't find how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my Nutch knowledge goes, you can't distinguish between images and thumbnails because the thumbnails are images themselves.

You need to add some logic yourself that is able to differentiate between thumbnails and actual images you are searching for.

You could e.g. verify if the image is part of an anchor that links to another image or something similar.

Comment: Yeah I realize that and that's why the question is not nutch specific. Just, how can this idea be implemented to avoid the thumbnails and reach the actual image...